# Weird stuttering when generating animated gifs using gifshot.js on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, html, html5-canvas, gif

Ok, so a little bit of background... I'm trying to generate animated gifs from animations done on an HTML5 canvas using JavaScript. Specifically, I'm adding data layers to a Mapbox GL JS map and looping through them.

On each iteration, I save the canvas element and transform it to a blob before calling URL.createObjectURL(blob) and setting that as the source to a new image. After the loop is finished I generate a gif using gifshot (https://github.com/yahoo/gifshot) and the images I previously created.

This process works perfectly in all browsers (mobile too!) EXCEPT on iPhone ios. On ios the gif has weird stutters and transparency issues. I have tried other gif creation libraies but all have the same issue on ios. Could it be a memory problem or something? I'm at my wit's end on this, so any help is greatly appreciated!

This is the code inside each loop:

```
var cv = map.getCanvas()
var oneImage = new Image();

cv.toBlob(function(blob) {  
    url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    oneImage.src = url

    images_arr.push(oneImage)
    i++;
    setTimeout(function(){
        gifLoop(images_arr);  
    },1000) 
})
```

and this is the code I call when the loop is finished:

```
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
recalculated_size = calculateAspectRatioFit(w, h, maxWidth, maxHeight)
w = recalculated_size.width
h = recalculated_size.height

gifshot.createGIF({
    'images': images_arr,
    'gifWidth': w,
    'gifHeight':h,
},function(obj) {
    if(!obj.error) {
        var image = dataURItoBlob(obj.image)
        image = URL.createObjectURL(image);

        var animatedImage = document.getElementById('gif');
        animatedImage.src = image

        var link = $('#gif-link');
        link.attr('href',image);
        filename = curr_layer_id + '_' + curr_time +'.gif'
        link.attr('download', filename);

      }
 });
```

[image: Here is an example of the issue I'm referring to]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post any pertinent code here in the actual question.

Comment: Is the problem displaying the gif, even if created on another working device? or (guessing this is the case by the linked gif) is it that gifs created on problem device don't work on all devices? Or some other combination? Is the linked gif a example, or did you simulate the effect as demonstration?

Comment: @Blindman67 The problem is creating the gif on ios, the gif created on any ios browser looks like the posted image on any platform. The linked gif is direct output from an ios browser.